# How can I keep some data between builds in TeamCity?

Tags: teamcity

Github Actions support [actions/cache](https://github.com/actions/cache) to keep some artifacts from previous build, like dependencies or build output. Is there any way to do the same with TeamCity?

I've looked through build artifacts, but seems they are not available for following builds, only for manual download. Now we are using docker image with dependencies, but it's not very convenient because we have to update that image manually. Also we can't cache compiled classes to save time for compilation if previous attempt was partially successful.